# How to make subtree ignore touch?

Tags: flutter

Consider a `Stack` with 2 children. How to make the widget on top (along with all its children) ignore touches so the bottom widget can handle them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are looking for is the [`IgnorePointer`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/IgnorePointer-class.html) widget, which will enable you to ignore any touch events to its subtree.

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap the widget which should ignore touch  in `AbsorbPointer`.

Example:

```
Stack(
  children: [
    AbsorbPointer(child: Child1()), // it will ignore touches
    Child2(),
  ]
)
```